# Solve system of inequations with absolute values

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
|c_1-3c_2|<\delta \\ 
|c_1+c_2|<\delta
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Could you provide how $|c_1|$ and $|c_2|$ are limited by $\delta$ in such a form: $|c_i| < k\delta $.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider on plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ the four lines:
$$
x - 3y = \delta\\
x - 3y = -\delta\\
x + y = \delta\\
x + y = -\delta
$$
They form a parallelogram. The region you describe is the interior of this parallelogram. If you make a drawing, you will see clearly that
$$
|c_1| <\delta \quad \text{and} \quad |c_2| < \delta/2.
$$